# Formatting dates inside a Function<T,R>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to format a date inside a Functional Interface but I don't know if it is possible

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyyyyy");

List<MenuPrice> menuPrices = findAll(restaurant);

menuPrices.parallelStream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dt1.format(MenuPrice::getUpdateDate)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, but not with a method reference:

```
Map<String,List<MenuPrice>>
    menuPrices.parallelStream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> dt1.format(m.getUpdateDate())));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a method for that btw, to make things slightly more readable:

```
private static String formatUpdatedDate(MenuPrice menu){ 
     return dt1.format(menu.getUpdatedDate());
}
```

And use it:

```
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YourClass::formatUpdatedDate)
```

Comment: And the `SimpleDateFormat` variable could perfectly be a local variable inside the static method :)